# ASP.NET Core MVC with Razor Pages (can't return object from a different model)

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I'm making a call to Azure tables in a method I've created as part of the Razor page model (cs) file. The results are of type `TenantEntityModel`. I'd like to simply display those results in my view.

Is it possible to do this and if so, what needs to be in my Razor page model?

The method in my Razor model has the following call:

```
TenantEntityModel Result = await azureTableConnection.TenantLookupAsync(azureTableConnection, domainName, id);
```

I thought I could just use `@Model.Result.DomainName` in the view however there is no reference to this object as `Result` didn't exist in my Razor model. So I tried adding it to my Razor model as:

```
public TenantEntityModel Result { get; }
```

This allows me to access the properties of the `Result` in my Razor view. If I put a break point before the `return Page()` statement I can see the `Result` object has the properties I'm after. However when the view is rendered, the `Model` object's `Result` property is null and I get:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I've also tried adding `BindProperty` as follows:

```
[BindProperty]
public TenantEntityModel Result { get; }
```

...but that didn't work either. So I'm at a loss on how to take the results of a query, populate an object with a model from a different class, then render a page with the results of that object.

**View code:**

```
@page
@model ApiKeyModel
@if (@Model.Result.ApiKey == null)
            {
                //show the button
                <button name="CreateApiKey" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create new API Key</button>
            }
```

**Controller code:**

```
public class ApiKeyModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<UserRegistrationExtension> _userManager;
    private readonly ILogger<PersonalDataModel> _logger;

    [BindProperty]
    public TenantEntityModel Result { get; set; }

    public ApiKeyModel(
        UserManager<UserRegistrationExtension> userManager,
        ILogger<PersonalDataModel> logger)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
    {
        // need to validate if account exists first
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
        }

        var domainName = user.Office365DomainName;
        var id = user.Id;
        AzureTableConnection azureTableConnection = new AzureTableConnection();
        TenantEntityModel Result = await azureTableConnection.TenantLookupAsync(azureTableConnection, domainName, id);

        return Page();
    }
```

Comment: Where's your controller and view code?

Comment: edited. Just curious...does the 'controller code' in a Razor page consist of the 'code behind' of the view page? If so, where is the 'model'? Might be a dumb question but I thought Razor pages stuffed everything in a .cs file (controller and model).

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I forgot that this is Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your PageModel code to this. You were creating a local variable `TenantEntityModel Result` instead of assigning value to your property.

```
public class ApiKeyModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<UserRegistrationExtension> _userManager;
    private readonly ILogger<PersonalDataModel> _logger;

    [BindProperty]
    public TenantEntityModel Result { get; set; }

    public ApiKeyModel(
        UserManager<UserRegistrationExtension> userManager,
        ILogger<PersonalDataModel> logger)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
    {
        // need to validate if account exists first
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
        }

        var domainName = user.Office365DomainName;
        var id = user.Id;
        AzureTableConnection azureTableConnection = new AzureTableConnection();
        Result = await azureTableConnection.TenantLookupAsync(azureTableConnection, domainName, id);

        return Page();
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you John!! That makes sense. So there is no need to put the class name (model) in front of the variable I suppose. Is this because my class defines it's type earlier through the `public TenantEntityModel Result {get; set;}` piece?

Comment: Yes, that is the property accessible by your view code!

Comment: "You were creating a local variable TenantEntityModel Result instead" - ugh! This tripped me up for a couple hours just now. Doh! :)

Answer (score 1):

For passing model between `View` and `PageModel` in `Razor Page`, you need to set the value for the defined model `public TenantEntityModel Result { get; set; }` instead of defineing a new object `TenantEntityModel Result`.

Try to change `OnGet()` to:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
{
    // need to validate if account exists first
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
    }

    var domainName = user.Office365DomainName;
    var id = user.Id;
    AzureTableConnection azureTableConnection = new AzureTableConnection();
    Result = await azureTableConnection.TenantLookupAsync(azureTableConnection, domainName, id);

    return Page();
}
```